# Is there a way to get pop-ups with bash autocomplete in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

Is there a way to have pop-ups instead of list of next commands for bash autocomplete in Ubuntu terminal?

I've created an autocomplete script for one of my applications which shows the next word after pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
But these words get displayed on the terminal like below:

```
$ command opt<TAB>
option1 option2
```

I am planning to enhance the experience by having a popup instead of showing the next words on terminal. (something similar to AutoComplPop in Vim)

Please suggest if this seems like a good idea and if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project. I would create a short cut with `shift`+`Tab` and assign it to my GUI script. Inside the script I would use zenity or yad. I'd probably download the source code for the current `Tab` key handler.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `zsh`, [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)?

You can enable zsh-autosuggestions on your `.zshrc` like this

```
plugins=(git
         zsh-autosuggestions
        )
```

It is very similar to what you described in your question.